# substitute in the filename

Tags: regular-expressions, query-replace

In Dired Query and Replace, can we substitute in the filename being visited? For example, I want to substitute "solve" in all *.mod files with the filename *.mod.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you want to do.  Could you edit your post to elaborate, please?

Comment: Say I have 100 *.mod files, each of them contain the word "solve". I would like to replace "solve" with the corresponding filename.

Comment: sorry, that doesn't clarify it. Do you mean the filename contains "solve", or that the string "solve" occurs in the contents of the file?

Comment: I'm guessing I think that this is what you want to do:

1. Find all files whose names match `*.mod` and whose contents contain the word `solve`.

2. Replace the word `solve` in each of those files with the name of the file.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if the OP clarifies the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that what you want to do is this:

1. Find all files whose names match `*.mod` and whose contents contain the word `solve`.
2. Replace the word `solve` in each of those files with the name of the file.

If so, one answer might be to use `Q` in Dired, searching for `solve`, and to use a replacement expression such as `\,(buffer-file-name)`, to replace `solve` with the name of the file currently visited (where the `solve` occurrence is).

If you want, you can also issue a `find` command using `find-dired.el`, to open Dired with just the files that contain `solve`.  And then use `Q` on all of them (just mark them all, or use `C-u C-u Q` with [Dired+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus)).

Comment: Great answer, no wait:  A damn great answer! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably asking for writable dired (wdired) feature. In any open dired buffer, make it writable with

```
C-x C-q
```

then use search/replace as any normal buffer to substitute "solve" with whatever you want. Notice only the filenames are editable. Once you finish editing the filenames, you need to commit the changes with

```
C-c C-c
```

or if you want to undo or cancel the changes, use

```
C-c ESC
```